# Collection for fast add, get and remove random element

Tags: java, collections

Not a big question really. What collection would be good for fast add, get and removal of a random element?

The items don't have to retain any kind of order.

I'm developing a snake game and I'm keeping track of unoccupied cells in the game area (to be able to quickly pick a new place for the apple once it's eaten).

Here "fast" can be O(log n) or O(1).

Comment: Do you want a `List` or a `Set`?

Comment: @pbabcdefp for both random removal is linear at worst

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend a balanced binary tree. Insertion / removal will be O(log(n)) and selecting a random element will be a matter of randomly walking down the branches to a leaf, O(log(n)).

If looking up an unoccupied spot for the apple is a relatively uncommon operation compared to adding/removing occupied cells, I would go for a `LinkedHashSet`:

- Make a cell unoccupied: `unoccupied.add(pos)`, O(1) (amortized)
- Make a cell occupied: `unoccupied.remove(pos)`, O(1)
- Find a random unoccupied cell:

  ```
  if (unoccupied.isEmpty()) throw something;
  int i = random.nextInt(unoccupied.size());
  Iterator<Pos> iter = unoccupied.iterator();
  while (i-- > 0)
      iter.next();
  return iter.next();
  ```

(Using a `LinkedHashMap` instead of a `HashMap` ensures O(n) on the last operation.)

An `ArrayList` will have O(n) for removal. A `LinkedList` or `HashSet` will have O(n) for looking up a random element.

Comment: However all the cells are not leaves.

Comment: Depends on how you construct your tree I guess.

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja Here is an implementation that answers your question http://www.nayuki.io/page/avl-tree-list

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja However I strongly suspect that for a snake game you should just use a `HashSet`. You don't need anything complicated like a balanced tree unless your data is huge and you'll notice the difference between O(log n) and O(n).

Comment: @pbabcdefp The data size is significant

Answer (score 0):

The best `List` is `LinkedList` 
Remove and insert happens in O(1) but retrieve the position happens in O(n).
Retrieve the element in position n is O(n).

Otherwyse you can use `TreeSet`. All operations are granted in O(log n).

If you can use a key to retrieve your element you can use a `Map`. `HashMap` has insert retrieve remove in O(1)

Answer (score -1):

HashMap, it has a complexity of O(1) for all of three (in most cases):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: Did you mean `HashSet`? If so, how would you randomly select an element in O(1)? You don't know the distribution of the buckets.

Comment: If a `HashMap` (or a `HashSet`) has size `n`, how can you remove a random one of the `n` entries in O(1)?

Comment: I can't reliably remove from the map by a random index, at least in constant time. Maybe I could do it in O(log n) with TreeMap